# Power BI: How to get ONLY ONE total for each row in a matrix with multiple dimensions

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a matrix that has two row's dimensions- one for the country, and one that shows different KPIs. Then I have two dimensions for columns - one with the product name and one with the product logo. Basically all KPI's for each country broken down by product:

[image: matrix view]

What I need to have is a total for each row, e.g. total KPI1 for all products, then total KPI2 for all products and so on. 
However, when I go to the formatting tab and turn subtotals to be ON, it appears in this way:

[image: Matrix with totals]

It gives me a total for each product separately which is basically the same number. Is there any way to have only 1 total for the whole row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Format > Subtotal and turn on `Per column level`. Then you can specify which levels you want to show subtotals for below that toggle.